# animating glutWireSphere

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

How can I get one wire sphere to stay stationary while another one translates?

Here is my code right now:

```
void animate ()
{
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);    
    glPushMatrix ();

    glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutWireSphere (1.0, 20, 20);

    glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix ();
    glTranslatef (0, 0.01, 0);
    glutWireSphere (0.2, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix ();

    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush ();
    glSwapBuffers ();

    glutTimerFunc (10, animate);
}
```

Currently all that happens is that both spheres are stationary. The behavior I want is to have the larger red sphere to stay still while the smaller green sphere slowly translates up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is you are translating on the y-axis by the same amount each frame. Your matrix is set to identity each frame, so your smaller green sphere is always at `(0.0,0.01,0.0)`.

Try keeping track of the position, and increment.

```
static float yPos = 0.0f;

glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix ();
glTranslatef (0, yPos, 0);
glutWireSphere (0.2, 20, 20);
glPopMatrix ();

yPos += 0.01f;
```

Comment: Wow its so obvious...I need more coffee

Thanks for helping me